# part of a c++ program which mods a game using code injection

Tags: c++, windows, assembly

https://github.com/speedrun-program/amnesia_load_screen_tool/blob/main/code_injection.cpp

https://github.com/speedrun-program/amnesia_load_screen_tool/blob/main/file_helper.h

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "file_helper.h"

typedef LONG(__stdcall* NTFUNCTION)(HANDLE);

const wchar_t steamName[] = L"Amnesia.exe";
const wchar_t nosteamName[] = L"Amnesia_NoSteam.exe";
const char flashbackNameFile[] = "flashback_names.txt";
const uint32_t flashbackSkipInstructionsSize = 128;
const uint32_t flashbackWaitInstructionsSize = 128;

class ProcessHelper
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> buffer;
    uint32_t memoryOffset = 0;
    uint32_t bytesLeft = 0;
    HANDLE amnesiaHandle = nullptr;
    uint32_t amnesiaMemoryLocation = (uint32_t)-1;
    DWORD pageSize = 0;
    int bufferPosition = 0;

    ProcessHelper(const ProcessHelper& fhelper) = delete;
    ProcessHelper& operator=(ProcessHelper other) = delete;
    ProcessHelper(ProcessHelper&&) = delete;
    ProcessHelper& operator=(ProcessHelper&&) = delete;

    ProcessHelper(DWORD pid)
    {
        amnesiaHandle = OpenProcess(
            PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME,
            false,
            pid
        );

        SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
        GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
        pageSize = sysInfo.dwPageSize;
        buffer = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(pageSize);
        bufferPosition = pageSize; // this initial value lets the first read happen on the first call to getByte
    }

    ~ProcessHelper()
    {
        if (amnesiaHandle != nullptr)
        {
            CloseHandle(amnesiaHandle);
        }
    }

    bool checkIfPathIsToAmnesia(const std::wstring& filepathBuffer)
    {
        // if L'\\' isn't found, filenamePosition will increase from npos to 0
        size_t filenamePosition = filepathBuffer.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1;
        int filenameSize = wcslen(&filepathBuffer[filenamePosition]);

        if ((filenameSize != (sizeof(steamName) / sizeof(wchar_t)) - 1 && filenameSize != (sizeof(nosteamName) / sizeof(wchar_t)) - 1)
            || (wcscmp(&filepathBuffer[filenamePosition], steamName) != 0 && wcscmp(&filepathBuffer[filenamePosition], nosteamName) != 0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool checkIfProcessIsAmnesia()
    {
        std::wstring filepathBuffer(512 - 1, L'\0'); // - 1 because a character is used for a null terminator on modern implementations

        DWORD queryFullProcessImageNameResult = 0;
        if (amnesiaHandle != nullptr) // this check gets rid of warning C6387
        {
            while (queryFullProcessImageNameResult == 0)
            {
                DWORD filepathBufferSize = filepathBuffer.size() - 1; // - 1 because writing to filepathBuffer.size() position is undefined
                queryFullProcessImageNameResult = QueryFullProcessImageName(amnesiaHandle, 0, &filepathBuffer[0], &filepathBufferSize);
                if (queryFullProcessImageNameResult == 0)
                {
                    DWORD errorNumber = GetLastError();
                    if (errorNumber == 122) // buffer too small error
                    {
                        filepathBuffer.clear();
                        filepathBuffer.resize(((filepathBufferSize + 2) * 2) - 1, L'\0'); // resizing to the next power of 2
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("error when using GetModuleBaseName: %d\n", GetLastError());
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if (filepathBufferSize >= 32767) // this should never happen
                {
                    printf("ERROR: file path size from QueryFullProcessImageName somehow exceeded 32767 characters\n");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // if L'\\' isn't found, filenamePosition will increase from npos to 0
        if (!checkIfPathIsToAmnesia(filepathBuffer))
        {
            printf("process name wasn't Amnesia.exe or Amnesia_NoSteam.exe when checking it using GetModuleBaseName: %ls\n", &filepathBuffer[0]);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool findExecutableMemoryLocation()
    {
        std::wstring filepathBuffer(512 - 1, L'\0'); // - 1 because a character is used for a null terminator on modern implementations

        uint32_t queryAddress = 0;
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = {};
        if (VirtualQueryEx(amnesiaHandle, (LPCVOID)queryAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) == 0) // checking if VirtualQueryEx works
        {
            printf("error when using VirtualQueryEx: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return false;
        }

        // finding start of Amnesia.exe or Amnesia_NoSteam.exe memory
        DWORD filepathBufferSize = 0;
        DWORD charactersWritten = 0;
        size_t filepathLength = (size_t)-1;
        do
        {
            if (queryAddress != 0) // this check gets rid of warning C6387
            {
                do
                {
                    filepathBufferSize = filepathBuffer.size() - 1; // - 1 because writing to filepathBuffer.size() position is undefined
                    charactersWritten = GetMappedFileName(
                        amnesiaHandle,
                        (LPVOID)queryAddress,
                        &filepathBuffer[0],
                        filepathBufferSize
                    );

                    if (filepathBufferSize == charactersWritten)
                    {
                        if (filepathBufferSize >= 32767) // this should never happen
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        filepathBuffer.clear();
                        filepathBuffer.resize(((filepathBufferSize + 2) * 2) - 1, L'\0'); // resizing to the next power of 2
                    }
                }
                while (filepathBufferSize == charactersWritten); // if this is true then filepathBuffer wasn't big enough
            }

            if (checkIfPathIsToAmnesia(filepathBuffer))
            {
                filepathLength = charactersWritten;
                break;
            }

            queryAddress += mbi.RegionSize;
        }
        while (VirtualQueryEx(amnesiaHandle, (LPCVOID)queryAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) != 0);

        if (filepathLength == (size_t)-1)
        {
            printf("couldn't find Amnesia.exe or Amnesia_NoSteam.exe memory location\n");
            return false;
        }

        // finding the .text area
        std::wstring filepathBufferCopy = filepathBuffer;

        do
        {
            if (mbi.Protect == PAGE_EXECUTE_READ)
            {
                amnesiaMemoryLocation = queryAddress;
                bytesLeft = mbi.RegionSize;
                memoryOffset = queryAddress - pageSize; // this will overflow to 0 on the first call to getByte
                return true;
            }

            if (queryAddress != 0) // this check gets rid of warning C6387
            {
                charactersWritten = GetMappedFileName(
                    amnesiaHandle,
                    (LPVOID)queryAddress,
                    &filepathBuffer[0],
                    filepathBufferSize
                );
            }

            if (charactersWritten != filepathLength || filepathBuffer != filepathBufferCopy) // no longer looking at exe memory
            {
                break;
            }

            queryAddress += mbi.RegionSize;
        }
        while (VirtualQueryEx(amnesiaHandle, (LPCVOID)queryAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) != 0);

        printf("couldn't find .text area in Amnesia.exe or Amnesia_NoSteam.exe memory\n");
        return false;
    }

    bool getByte(unsigned char& b)
    {
        if (bytesLeft == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (bufferPosition == pageSize)
        {
            bufferPosition = 0;
            memoryOffset += pageSize;
            bool readSucceeded = ReadProcessMemory(
                amnesiaHandle,
                (LPCVOID)memoryOffset,
                (LPVOID)buffer.get(),
                pageSize,
                nullptr
            );

            if (!readSucceeded)
            {
                printf("ProcessHelper ReadProcessMemory error in getByte: %d\nat memory address: %u\n", GetLastError(), memoryOffset);
                return false;
            }
        }

        b = buffer[bufferPosition];
        bufferPosition++;
        bytesLeft--;

        return true;
    }
};

struct SavedInstructions
{
    unsigned char gettingSoundHandler[14]{};
    unsigned char beforeFadeOutAllBytes[7]{};
    unsigned char sleepCallBytes[6]{};
    unsigned char loadEndBytes[5]{};
    uint32_t stopFunctionLocation = 0;
    uint32_t isPlayingLocation = 0;
    uint32_t beforeFadeOutAllLocation = 0;
    uint32_t loadEndLocation = 0;
    bool isSteamVersion = false;
};

DWORD searchUsingSnapshotHandle(SavedInstructions& si, PROCESSENTRY32& processEntry, HANDLE snapshot)
{
    if (!Process32First(snapshot, &processEntry))
    {
        printf("error when using Process32First: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return (DWORD)-1;
    }

    do
    {
        if ((si.isSteamVersion = (wcscmp(processEntry.szExeFile, steamName) == 0)) || wcscmp(processEntry.szExeFile, nosteamName) == 0)
        {
            return processEntry.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &processEntry));

    return (DWORD)-1;
}

DWORD findAmnesiaPid(SavedInstructions& si)
{
    DWORD amnesiaPid = (DWORD)-1;

    PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry{};
    processEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("error when using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return amnesiaPid;
    }
    amnesiaPid = searchUsingSnapshotHandle(si, processEntry, snapshot);
    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (amnesiaPid == (DWORD)-1)
    {
        printf("couldn't find amnesia process\n");
    }

    return amnesiaPid;
}

bool findNtFunctions(NTFUNCTION& NtSuspendProcess, NTFUNCTION& NtResumeProcess)
{
    HMODULE ntdllHandle = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll");
    if (!ntdllHandle)
    {
        printf("WARNING: error using GetModuleHandle to find ntdll.dll: %d\nAmnesia won't be suspended during code injection\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    NtSuspendProcess = (NTFUNCTION)GetProcAddress(ntdllHandle, "NtSuspendProcess");
    if (!NtSuspendProcess)
    {
        printf("WARNING: error using GetProcAddress to find NtSuspendProcess: %d\nAmnesia won't be suspended during code injection\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    NtResumeProcess = (NTFUNCTION)GetProcAddress(ntdllHandle, "NtResumeProcess");
    if (!NtResumeProcess)
    {
        printf("WARNING: error using GetProcAddress to find NtResumeProcess: %d\nAmnesia won't be suspended during code injection\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void addNewValueToMemorySlice(unsigned char* memorySlice, size_t size, unsigned char newEndValue)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        memorySlice[i] = memorySlice[i + 1];
    }
    memorySlice[size - 1] = newEndValue;
}

// this is fast enough for the size of the game
// if it needs to be faster, try making memorySlice a circular buffer
bool findInstructions(SavedInstructions& si, ProcessHelper& ph)
{
    unsigned char b = 0;
    unsigned char memorySlice[16]{}; // give this at least the size of the longest byte pattern

    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(memorySlice); i++)
    {
        if (!ph.getByte(b))
        {
            return false;
        }
        memorySlice[i] = b;
    }

    int locationsFound = 0; // if this ends up being greater than 5, there were duplicate injection location patterns
    bool isv = si.isSteamVersion; // on the steam version, the first mov instruction is 6 bytes long instead of 5
    for (size_t i = 0; ph.getByte(b); i++)
    {
        addNewValueToMemorySlice(memorySlice, sizeof(memorySlice), b);

        if (memorySlice[0] == 0xf6 && memorySlice[1] == 0x74 && memorySlice[7] == 0x75 && memorySlice[9] == 0x80)
        {
            locationsFound++;
            si.stopFunctionLocation = ph.amnesiaMemoryLocation + i - 16;
        }
        else if (memorySlice[0] == 0x48 && memorySlice[8] == 0xd0 && memorySlice[9] == 0x5d)
        {
            locationsFound++;
            si.isPlayingLocation = ph.amnesiaMemoryLocation + i - 17;
        }
        else if (memorySlice[0] == 0x75 && memorySlice[2] == 0x56 && memorySlice[4] == 0x15 && memorySlice[9] == 0x8b)
        {
            locationsFound++;
            memcpy(si.sleepCallBytes, &memorySlice[3], sizeof(si.sleepCallBytes));
        }
        else if (
            (memorySlice[5] == 0xff && memorySlice[6] == 0x50 && memorySlice[8] == 0xe8 && memorySlice[13] == 0x2b)
            || (si.isSteamVersion && memorySlice[5] == 0xff && memorySlice[6] == 0xd0 && memorySlice[7] == 0xe8 && memorySlice[13] == 0x45))
        {
            locationsFound++;
            si.loadEndLocation = ph.amnesiaMemoryLocation + i;

            if (memorySlice[0] == 0xe9) // the jump instruction is already there, so amnesia must have already been injected
            {
                printf("amnesia is already injected\n");
                return false;
            }

            memcpy(si.loadEndBytes, memorySlice, sizeof(si.loadEndBytes));
        }
        else if (memorySlice[8 + isv] == 0x40 && memorySlice[10 + isv] == 0x8b && memorySlice[11 + isv] == 0x40 && memorySlice[14 + isv] == 0x01)
        {
            locationsFound++;
            memcpy(si.gettingSoundHandler, memorySlice, sizeof(si.gettingSoundHandler));

            i += 16 + isv;
            si.beforeFadeOutAllLocation = ph.amnesiaMemoryLocation + i;
            for (int n = 0; n < 16 + isv; n++)
            {
                ph.getByte(b);
                addNewValueToMemorySlice(memorySlice, sizeof(memorySlice), b);
            }

            if (memorySlice[0] == 0xe9) // the jump instruction is already there, so amnesia must have already been injected
            {
                printf("amnesia is already injected\n");
                return false;
            }

            memcpy(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes, memorySlice, sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes));
        }
    }

    bool allLocationsFound = (
        si.stopFunctionLocation != 0
        && si.isPlayingLocation != 0
        && si.beforeFadeOutAllLocation != 0
        && si.loadEndLocation != 0
        && si.sleepCallBytes[0] != 0
    );
    if (locationsFound > 5 || (locationsFound == 5 && !allLocationsFound))
    {
        printf("error: duplicate injection location patterns found\n");
        return false;
    }
    else if (allLocationsFound)
    {
        return true;
    }

    printf("couldn't find all instruction locations\n");
    return false;
}

// this needs to be done to find how much memory to allocate for the virtual pages
void preprocessFlashbackNames(FileHelper<char>& fh, uint32_t& howManyNames, uint32_t& longestName)
{
    char ch = '\0';

    uint32_t currentNameLength = 0;

    while (fh.getCharacter(ch))
    {
        if (ch == '\r') // windows puts this at the end of lines
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            if (currentNameLength > longestName)
            {
                longestName = currentNameLength;
            }
            howManyNames += currentNameLength > 0;
            currentNameLength = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNameLength++;
        }
    }

    // last line
    if (currentNameLength > longestName)
    {
        longestName = currentNameLength;
    }
    howManyNames += currentNameLength > 0;

    fh.resetFile();
}

bool setFlashbackNames(unsigned char* forExtraMemory, FileHelper<char>& fh, uint32_t startOffset, uint32_t spacePerName, uint32_t extraMemorySize)
{
    char ch = '\0';
    uint32_t writeOffset = startOffset;
    uint32_t nameSize = 0;

    while (fh.getCharacter(ch))
    {
        if (ch == '\r') // windows puts this at the end of lines
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            if (nameSize > 0)
            {
                memcpy(&forExtraMemory[writeOffset + spacePerName - 8], &nameSize, sizeof(nameSize));
                writeOffset += spacePerName;
                nameSize = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (nameSize == spacePerName - 9) // this shouldn't ever happen, flashback line names shouldn't need to be long enough to cause this
            {
                printf("a flashback line name was longer than expected, possibly because of integer overflow\n");
                return false;
            }
            else if (writeOffset + nameSize >= extraMemorySize) // this also shouldn't ever happen, there shouldn't need to be enough to cause this
            {
                printf("there were more flashback line names than expected, possibly because of integer overflow\n");
                return false;
            }

            forExtraMemory[writeOffset + nameSize] = (unsigned int)ch;
            nameSize++;
        }
    }
    if (nameSize > 0)
    {
        memcpy(&forExtraMemory[writeOffset + spacePerName - 8], &nameSize, sizeof(nameSize));
    }

    return true;
}

bool injectSkipInstructions(
    unsigned char* forExtraMemory,
    SavedInstructions& si,
    ProcessHelper& ph,
    uint32_t howManyNames,
    uint32_t spacePerName,
    uint32_t extraMemoryLocation,
    uint32_t extraMemorySize)
{
    // this is jumped to before a call instruction, so the caller-saved registers should already be saved
    unsigned char flashbackSkipInstructions[flashbackSkipInstructionsSize] = {
        // jmp destination from before calling cSoundHandler::FadeOutAll
        0xd9, 0x1c, 0x24,                         // 0000 // fstp dword ptr [esp] // copied
        0x6a, 0x01,                               // 0003 // push 0x01 // copied
        0x8b, 0xc8,                               // 0005 // mov ecx, eax // copied
        0x53,                                     // 0007 // push ebx // stack depth +4
        0x57,                                     // 0008 // push edi // stack depth +8
        0x51,                                     // 0009 // push ecx // cSoundHandler object // stack depth +12
        0xbb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0010 // mov ebx, start of first flashback name // check
        0x90,                                     // 0015 // nop so loop is aligned on byte 16
        // start of loop
        0x89, 0x1d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0016 // mov [string object ptr location], ebx // ptr to characters // check
        0x8b, 0xbb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0022 // mov edi, dword ptr [ebx + spacePerName - 8] // flashback name size
        0x89, 0x3d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0028 // mov dword ptr [string object size location], edi // check
        0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0034 // push string object ptr location // stack depth +16 // check
        0xe8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0039 // call cSoundHandler::Stop // stack depth +12
        0x8b, 0x0c, 0x24,                         // 0044 // mov ecx, dword ptr [esp] // cSoundHandler object
        0x81, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0047 // add ebx, spacePerName // start of next string data
        0x81, 0xfb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0053 // cmp ebx, end of flashback names // check
        0x75, 0xd3,                               // 0059 // jnz -45
        // end of loop

        0x59,                                     // 0061 // pop ecx // stack depth +8
        0x5f,                                     // 0062 // pop edi // stack depth +4
        0x5b,                                     // 0063 // pop ebx // stack depth +0
        0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0064 // jmp to before calling cSoundHandler::FadeOutAll, 0048baad
        0x90,                                     // 0069 // nop
    };

    unsigned char jmpInstruction[sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes)] = {0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90, 0x90};

    uint32_t stdStringCapacity = spacePerName - 1;
    memcpy(&forExtraMemory[sizeof(flashbackSkipInstructions) + 20], &stdStringCapacity, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t startOffset = sizeof(flashbackSkipInstructions) + 64; // 64 bytes used for std::string object + padding

    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[0], si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes, sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes));

    uint32_t firstFlashbackNameLocation = extraMemoryLocation + startOffset;
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[11], &firstFlashbackNameLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t stringObjectPtrLocation = extraMemoryLocation + sizeof(flashbackSkipInstructions);
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[18], &stringObjectPtrLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[35], &stringObjectPtrLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t flashbackNameSizeOffset = spacePerName - 8;
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[24], &flashbackNameSizeOffset, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t stringObjectSizeLocation = extraMemoryLocation + sizeof(flashbackSkipInstructions) + 16;
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[30], &stringObjectSizeLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t stopFunctionOffset = si.stopFunctionLocation - (extraMemoryLocation + 44);
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[40], &stopFunctionOffset, sizeof(stopFunctionOffset));

    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[49], &spacePerName, sizeof(spacePerName));

    uint32_t endOfFlashbackNames = extraMemoryLocation + startOffset + (howManyNames * spacePerName);
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[55], &endOfFlashbackNames, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t fadeOutAllOffset = (si.beforeFadeOutAllLocation + sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes)) - (extraMemoryLocation + 69);
    memcpy(&flashbackSkipInstructions[65], &fadeOutAllOffset, sizeof(fadeOutAllOffset));

    memset(&flashbackSkipInstructions[70], 0xcc, sizeof(flashbackSkipInstructions) - 70); // int3

    memcpy(forExtraMemory, flashbackSkipInstructions, sizeof(flashbackSkipInstructions));

    SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;
    bool wpmSucceeded = false;

    wpmSucceeded = WriteProcessMemory(
        ph.amnesiaHandle,
        (LPVOID)extraMemoryLocation,
        (LPCVOID)forExtraMemory,
        extraMemorySize,
        nullptr
    );

    if (!wpmSucceeded)
    {
        printf("error when calling WriteProcessMemory to write to allocated virtual page(s): %d\nat memory address: %u\n", GetLastError(), extraMemoryLocation);
        return false;
    }

    uint32_t offsetFromCheckMapChange = (extraMemoryLocation + 0) - (si.beforeFadeOutAllLocation + 5);
    memcpy(&jmpInstruction[1], &offsetFromCheckMapChange, sizeof(offsetFromCheckMapChange));

    wpmSucceeded = WriteProcessMemory(
        ph.amnesiaHandle,
        (LPVOID)si.beforeFadeOutAllLocation,
        (LPCVOID)jmpInstruction,
        sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes),
        &bytesWritten
    );

    if (bytesWritten < sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes))
    {
        printf("JMP INSTRUCTION ONLY PARTIALLY WRITTEN IN CHECKMAPCHANGE\nRESTART AMNESIA OR IT WILL CRASH ON MAP CHANGE\nerror: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    else if (!wpmSucceeded)
    {
        printf("error when calling WriteProcessMemory to write jmp instruction in CheckMapChange: %d\nat memory address: %u\n", GetLastError(), si.beforeFadeOutAllLocation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool injectWaitInstructions(
    unsigned char* forExtraMemory,
    SavedInstructions& si,
    ProcessHelper& ph,
    uint32_t howManyNames,
    uint32_t spacePerName,
    uint32_t extraMemoryLocation,
    uint32_t extraMemorySize)
{
    // this is jumped to before a call instruction, so the caller-saved registers should already be saved
    unsigned char flashbackWaitInstructions[flashbackWaitInstructionsSize] = {
        0x53,                                     // 0000 // push ebx // stack depth +4
        0x57,                                     // 0001 // push edi // stack depth +8
        0x56,                                     // 0002 // push esi // stack depth +12
        0x51,                                     // 0003 // push ecx // steam version copied instructions need ecx // stack depth +16
        0x51,                                     // 0004 // push ecx // dummy push // stack depth +20
        0x51,                                     // 0005 // push ecx // dummy push // stack depth +24

        // jmp destination from near the end of the map load
        // starting with 13-14 bytes to get the cSoundHandler object in eax
        // the last byte is a nop instruction because the NoSteam version only uses 13 bytes to get the cSoundHandler object
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90, // 0006 // getting cSoundHandler object

        0x8b, 0xc8,                               // 0020 // mov ecx, eax // moving cSoundHandler object to ecx
        0x51,                                     // 0022 // push ecx // cSoundHandler object // stack depth +28
        0xbb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0023 // mov ebx, start of first flashback name
        0x31, 0xf6,                               // 0028 // xor esi, esi
        0x90, 0x90,                               // 0030 // nops so loop is aligned on byte 32
        // start of loop
        0x89, 0x1d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0032 // mov [string object ptr location], ebx // ptr to characters
        0x8b, 0xbb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0038 // mov edi, dword ptr [ebx + spacePerName - 8] // flashback name size
        0x89, 0x3d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0044 // mov dword ptr [string object size location], edi
        0x8b, 0x0c, 0x24,                         // 0050 // mov ecx, dword ptr [esp] // cSoundHandler object
        0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0053 // push string object ptr location // stack depth +32
        0xe8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0058 // call cSoundHandler::IsPlaying // stack depth +28
        0x09, 0xc6,                               // 0063 // or esi, eax
        0x81, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0065 // add ebx, spacePerName // start of next string data
        0x81, 0xfb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0071 // cmp ebx, end of flashback names
        0x75, 0xd1,                               // 0077 // jnz -47
        0x83, 0xfe, 0x00,                         // 0079 // cmp esi, 0
        0x74, 0x10,                               // 0082 // jz 16
        0x56,                                     // 0084 // push esi // stack depth +32 // esi should be 1 here
        0xff, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // 0085 // call Sleep // stack depth +28
        0xbb, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0091 // mov ebx, start of first flashback name
        0x31, 0xf6,                               // 0096 // xor esi, esi
        0x74, 0xbc,                               // 0098 // jz -68
        // end of loop

        0x83, 0xc4, 0x0c,                         // 0100 // add esp, 12 // stack depth +16
        0x59,                                     // 0103 // pop ecx // stack depth +12
        0x5e,                                     // 0104 // pop esi // stack depth +8
        0x5f,                                     // 0105 // pop edi // stack depth +4
        0x5b,                                     // 0106 // pop ebx // stack depth +0
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0107 // copied instructions
        0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,             // 0112 // jmp to end of load
        0x90,                                     // 0117 // nop
    };

    unsigned char jmpInstruction[sizeof(si.beforeFadeOutAllBytes)] = {0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    uint32_t stdStringCapacity = spacePerName - 1;
    memcpy(&forExtraMemory[sizeof(flashbackWaitInstructions) + 20], &stdStringCapacity, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t startOffset = sizeof(flashbackWaitInstructions) + 64; // 64 bytes used for std::string object + padding

    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[6], si.gettingSoundHandler, sizeof(si.gettingSoundHandler) - !(si.isSteamVersion));

    uint32_t firstFlashbackNameLocation = extraMemoryLocation + startOffset;
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[24], &firstFlashbackNameLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[92], &firstFlashbackNameLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t stringObjectPtrLocation = extraMemoryLocation + sizeof(flashbackWaitInstructions);
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[34], &stringObjectPtrLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[54], &stringObjectPtrLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t flashbackNameSizeOffset = spacePerName - 8;
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[40], &flashbackNameSizeOffset, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t stringObjectSizeLocation = extraMemoryLocation + sizeof(flashbackWaitInstructions) + 16;
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[46], &stringObjectSizeLocation, sizeof(uint32_t));

    uint32_t isPlayingOffset = si.isPlayingLocation - (extraMemoryLocation + 63);
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[59], &isPlayingOffset, sizeof(isPlayingOffset));

    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[67], &spacePerName, sizeof(spacePerName));

    uint32_t endOfFlashbackNames = extraMemoryLocation + startOffset + (howManyNames * spacePerName);
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[73], &endOfFlashbackNames, sizeof(uint32_t));

    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[85], si.sleepCallBytes, sizeof(si.sleepCallBytes));

    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[107], si.loadEndBytes, sizeof(si.loadEndBytes));

    uint32_t loadEndOffset = (si.loadEndLocation + sizeof(si.loadEndBytes)) - (extraMemoryLocation + 117);
    memcpy(&flashbackWaitInstructions[113], &loadEndOffset, sizeof(loadEndOffset));

    memset(&flashbackWaitInstructions[118], 0xcc, sizeof(flashbackWaitInstructions) - 118); // int3

    memcpy(forExtraMemory, flashbackWaitInstructions, sizeof(flashbackWaitInstructions));

    SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;
    bool wpmSucceeded = false;

    wpmSucceeded = WriteProcessMemory(
        ph.amnesiaHandle,
        (LPVOID)extraMemoryLocation,
        (LPCVOID)forExtraMemory,
        extraMemorySize,
        nullptr
    );

    if (!wpmSucceeded)
    {
        printf("error when calling WriteProcessMemory to write to allocated virtual page(s): %d\nat memory address: %u\n", GetLastError(), extraMemoryLocation);
        return false;
    }

    uint32_t offsetFromCheckMapChange = (extraMemoryLocation + 0) - (si.loadEndLocation + 5);
    memcpy(&jmpInstruction[1], &offsetFromCheckMapChange, sizeof(offsetFromCheckMapChange));

    wpmSucceeded = WriteProcessMemory(
        ph.amnesiaHandle,
        (LPVOID)si.loadEndLocation,
        (LPCVOID)jmpInstruction,
        sizeof(si.loadEndBytes),
        &bytesWritten
    );

    if (bytesWritten < sizeof(si.loadEndBytes))
    {
        printf("JMP INSTRUCTION ONLY PARTIALLY WRITTEN IN CHECKMAPCHANGE\nRESTART AMNESIA OR IT WILL CRASH ON MAP CHANGE\nerror: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    else if (!wpmSucceeded)
    {
        printf("error when calling WriteProcessMemory to write jmp instruction in CheckMapChange: %d\nat memory address: %u\n", GetLastError(), si.loadEndLocation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool injectWhileSuspended(ProcessHelper& ph, SavedInstructions& si, LPVOID& extraMemoryLocation, bool skipFlashbacks)
{
    if (!ph.findExecutableMemoryLocation())
    {
        return false;
    }
    size_t executableRegionSize = ph.bytesLeft;

    if (!findInstructions(si, ph))
    {
        return false;
    }

    uint32_t howManyNames = 0;
    uint32_t longestName = 0;
    uint32_t spacePerName = 0;
    uint32_t nameAreaOffset = 0;
    uint32_t extraMemorySize = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> forExtraMemory;

    // FileHelper<char> object is only used in this area, so this scope is used so it doesn't stay allocated longer than it's needed
    {
        FileHelper<char> fh(flashbackNameFile);
        preprocessFlashbackNames(fh, howManyNames, longestName);

        if (howManyNames == 0)
        {
            printf("no flashback line names found in %s\n", flashbackNameFile);
            return false;
        }

        spacePerName = (((longestName + 9) / 64) + (((longestName + 9) % 64) != 0)) * 64; // 8 bytes to store name size, 1 byte for null character
        nameAreaOffset = (skipFlashbacks ? flashbackSkipInstructionsSize : flashbackWaitInstructionsSize) + 64; // 64 bytes to store string object plus padding
        extraMemorySize = nameAreaOffset + (spacePerName * howManyNames);

        forExtraMemory = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(extraMemorySize);

        if (!setFlashbackNames(forExtraMemory.get(), fh, nameAreaOffset, spacePerName, extraMemorySize))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    extraMemoryLocation = VirtualAllocEx(
        ph.amnesiaHandle,
        nullptr,
        extraMemorySize,
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
    );
    if (extraMemoryLocation == nullptr)
    {
        printf("error when using VirtualAllocEx: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    bool injectionSucceeded = false;
    if (skipFlashbacks)
    {
        injectionSucceeded = injectSkipInstructions(forExtraMemory.get(), si, ph, howManyNames, spacePerName, (uint32_t)extraMemoryLocation, extraMemorySize);
    }
    else
    {
        injectionSucceeded = injectWaitInstructions(forExtraMemory.get(), si, ph, howManyNames, spacePerName, (uint32_t)extraMemoryLocation, extraMemorySize);
    }

    if (!injectionSucceeded)
    {
        bool extraMemoryFreed = VirtualFreeEx(
            ph.amnesiaHandle,
            extraMemoryLocation,
            0,
            MEM_RELEASE
        );
        extraMemoryLocation = nullptr;
        if (!extraMemoryFreed)
        {
            printf("WARNING: error when using VirtualFreeEx: %d\ncouldn't release VirtualAllocEx memory\n", GetLastError());
        }

        return false;
    }

    printf("amnesia has been injected\n");
    return true;
}

DWORD codeInjectionMain(bool skipFlashbacks)
{
    LPVOID extraMemoryLocation = nullptr; // this is here so the virtual pages can be released in the catch block if an unexpected error happens
    HANDLE amnesiaHandle = nullptr; // needed when catching exception

    try
    {
        // LiveSplit uses these functions, so they're probably safe to use even though they're undocumented
        NTFUNCTION NtSuspendProcess = nullptr;
        NTFUNCTION NtResumeProcess = nullptr;

        SavedInstructions si;

        DWORD amnesiaPid = findAmnesiaPid(si);

        if (amnesiaPid == (DWORD)-1)
        {
            printf("you can now close this window\n");
            return (DWORD)-1;
        }

        ProcessHelper ph(amnesiaPid);

        if (!ph.checkIfProcessIsAmnesia())
        {
            printf("you can now close this window\n");
            return (DWORD)-1;
        }

        amnesiaHandle = ph.amnesiaHandle;

        bool ntFunctionsFound = findNtFunctions(NtSuspendProcess, NtResumeProcess);

        if (ntFunctionsFound)
        {
            NtSuspendProcess(ph.amnesiaHandle);
        }

        bool injectionSucceeded = injectWhileSuspended(ph, si, extraMemoryLocation, skipFlashbacks);

        if (ntFunctionsFound)
        {
            NtResumeProcess(ph.amnesiaHandle);
        }

        return injectionSucceeded ? amnesiaPid : (DWORD)-1;
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        char const* fixC4101Warning = e.what();
        printf("unexpected error: %s\n", fixC4101Warning);

        if (extraMemoryLocation)
        {
            bool extraMemoryFreed = VirtualFreeEx(
                amnesiaHandle,
                extraMemoryLocation,
                0,
                MEM_RELEASE
            );
            extraMemoryLocation = nullptr;
            if (!extraMemoryFreed)
            {
                printf("WARNING: error when using VirtualFreeEx: %d\ncouldn't release VirtualAllocEx memory\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
    }

    return (DWORD)-1;
}
```

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

const size_t fhelperBufferSize = 8192;

template <typename T>
class FileHelper
{
public:
    FileHelper(const FileHelper& fhelper) = delete;
    FileHelper& operator=(FileHelper other) = delete;
    FileHelper(FileHelper&&) = delete;
    FileHelper& operator=(FileHelper&&) = delete;

    explicit FileHelper(const wchar_t* filename) // there isn't wfopen on linux
    {
#ifndef _WIN32
        throw std::runtime_error("FileHelper wchar_t* constructor only works on Windows");
#endif
        if (_wfopen_s(&_f, filename, L"rb") != 0 || !_f)
        {
            printf("FileHelper couldn't open %ls\n", filename);
            throw std::runtime_error("FileHelper fopen failure in const wchar_t* constructor");
        }
    }

    explicit FileHelper(const char* filename)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        if (fopen_s(&_f, filename, "rb") != 0 || !_f)
#else
        if (!(_f = fopen(filename, "rb")))
#endif
        {
            printf("FileHelper couldn't open %s\n", filename);
            throw std::runtime_error("FileHelper fopen failure in const char* constructor");
        }
    }

    ~FileHelper()
    {
        if (_f)
        {
            fclose(_f);
        }
    }

    bool getCharacter(T& ch)
    {
        if (_bufferPosition == _charactersRead)
        {
            _bufferPosition = 0;
            _charactersRead = (int)fread(_buffer.get(), sizeof(T), fhelperBufferSize / sizeof(T), _f);

            if (!_charactersRead)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ch = _buffer[_bufferPosition];
        _bufferPosition++;

        return true;
    }

    void resetFile()
    {
        if (fseek(_f, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("FileHelper fseek failure in resetFile");
        }

        _bufferPosition = 0;
        _charactersRead = 0;
    }

private:
    FILE* _f = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> _buffer = std::make_unique<T[]>(fhelperBufferSize / sizeof(T));
    int _bufferPosition = 0;
    int _charactersRead = 0;
};
```

This is code for a mod for the open source game Amnesia: The Dark Descent which injects it to make it either skip or wait through dialogue during load screens.

example: https://youtu.be/mMikDj3KSGg

If it's skipping the dialogue, it injects here: https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent/blob/acc95cdedd6c94db89dc924eb9afa23185df562f/amnesia/src/game/LuxMapHandler.cpp#L633

And then it skips by calling this function for each possible dialogue: https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent/blob/acc95cdedd6c94db89dc924eb9afa23185df562f/HPL2/core/sources/sound/SoundHandler.cpp#L709

If it's waiting through the dialogue, it injects here: https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent/blob/acc95cdedd6c94db89dc924eb9afa23185df562f/amnesia/src/game/LuxMapHandler.cpp#L685

And then it checks if any of the dialogues are playing by calling this function for each possible dialogue: https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent/blob/acc95cdedd6c94db89dc924eb9afa23185df562f/HPL2/core/sources/sound/SoundHandler.cpp#L797

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It isn't clear why `file_helper.h` makes an attempt to be portable since `code_injection.cpp` is not portable. If you want most of the code to be portable, break the code into more files and limit the code that requires WIN32 code - such as the process ID code - to a particular file.

Since this is C++ rather than C, it isn't clear why the code is using C input and output. Specifically, why is the code using `printf()` rather than `std::cout`?

All error messages are going to `stdout`, rather than `stderr`. If the code continues to use C rather than C++ input and output report errors using `fprintf(stderr, ERROR MESSAGE);`.

It is not clear why the code is using low-level C file functions such as `fopen()` and `fclose()`. Streams would be a better way in C++.

Allow the compiler to point out possible issues by increasing the warning levels. I am compiling using Visual Studio 2022 and I am getting the following warning messages:

> code_injection.cpp(63,1): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(83,1): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(124,1): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPCVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(140,1): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(143,1): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(167,32): warning C4244: '+=': conversion from 'SIZE_T' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(168,1): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPCVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(184,32): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'SIZE_T' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(193,1): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(204,32): warning C4244: '+=': conversion from 'SIZE_T' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(205,1): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPCVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(224,1): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPCVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(361,72): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(366,69): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(378,62): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(394,71): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
> code_injection.cpp(597,36): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(614,44): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(739,36): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(756,35): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'LPVOID' of greater size
> code_injection.cpp(835,140): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'LPVOID' to 'uint32_t'
> code_injection.cpp(835,140): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'LPVOID' to 'uint32_t'
> code_injection.cpp(839,140): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'LPVOID' to 'uint32_t'
> code_injection.cpp(839,140): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'LPVOID' to 'uint32_t'

Based on the above warning messages it isn't clear why the code is using `std::uint32_t` rather than just `unsigned int` or `std::size_t`. In some cases I might suggest a bool variable rather than an integer.

It isn't clear why the following code is using arrays of characters rather than C++ strings, although if the code continues to use C input and output functions that might be necessary.

> ```
> const wchar_t steamName[] = L"Amnesia.exe";
> const wchar_t nosteamName[] = L"Amnesia_NoSteam.exe";
> const char flashbackNameFile[] = "flashback_names.txt";
> ```

The `if` statements in the following code are too complex and should be simplified. The code is also less clear because the comparisons are using raw numbers (*Magic numbers*) rather than *symbolic constants*.

> ```
>         if (memorySlice[0] == 0xf6 && memorySlice[1] == 0x74 && memorySlice[7] == 0x75 && memorySlice[9] == 0x80)
>         {
>             locationsFound++;
>             si.stopFunctionLocation = ph.amnesiaMemoryLocation + i - 16;
>         }
>         else if (memorySlice[0] == 0x48 && memorySlice[8] == 0xd0 && memorySlice[9] == 0x5d)
>         {
>             locationsFound++;
>             si.isPlayingLocation = ph.amnesiaMemoryLocation + i - 17;
>         }
>         else if (memorySlice[0] == 0x75 && memorySlice[2] == 0x56 && memorySlice[4] == 0x15 && memorySlice[9] == 0x8b)
>         {
>             locationsFound++;
>             memcpy(si.sleepCallBytes, &memorySlice[3], sizeof(si.sleepCallBytes));
>         }
>         else if (
>             (memorySlice[5] == 0xff && memorySlice[6] == 0x50 && memorySlice[8] == 0xe8 && memorySlice[13] == 0x2b)
>             || (si.isSteamVersion && memorySlice[5] == 0xff && memorySlice[6] == 0xd0 && memorySlice[7] == 0xe8 && memorySlice[13] ==
> 0x45))
>         {
> ```

The class `ProcessHelper` should be in its own header file (ProcessHelper.h) and the functions should be in ProcessHelper.cpp; this might make some portion of the code more portable.

It isn't clear why you want to embed assembly code rather than implement the functions in C++ which would make it easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Storing pointers as explicitly sized integers is terrifying.

Comment: C++17 has C++ file handling, rather than having to rely on the old C style file handling, unless you're using that for a specific purpose, in which case that reasoning should at least be in a comment. Also perhaps this code should just be written in straight C as there are so much C style syntax. C++2x is now a very different animal to just straight C.